# Force DVDs to be auto-mounted using "unhide" option by default?

Tags: gnome, mount, dvd, automount

Is there a way to force DVDs to be auto-mounted using the "unhide" option by default? Currently, in order to see hidden files on a DVD that Ubuntu has auto-mounted, I have to unmount it and then re-mount manually like this:

```
sudo mount -t udf -o ro,unhide /dev/cdrom ~/cdrom0/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a text editor (not a word processor!) and edit the file /etc/fstab (note you need to be root or use sudo to do this.)

One of the lines should concern the DVD/CD, something like:

```
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

In the forth column add unhide, like this:

```
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8,unhide 0       0
```

Save this and it should get you what you want on the next mount.
I'm not real sure if the auto-mounter reads fstab each time, but worst case it should work after a reboot.

Hope that helps